# Displaying multipule image that was uploaded in array in a view page and in a datatable

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am designing an asset register, and I am trying to upload multiple images to an ID as away to identify the asset easier, but I am struggling to display one small image in my data table and multiple images in my view page.

I have tried with a foreach loop and tried to echo files from my database, but every time I am getting a small grayed out images in my views and tables

Controller

```
        $data = array(
            'formTitle' => 'Create Asset',
            'title' => 'Create Asset',
        );


        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('asset_name', 'Asset Name', 'trim|required|callback_select_validate');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('asset_description', 'Asset Description', 'trim|required|callback_category_validate');

        $postData = $this->input->post();


        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
                $data['supplier'] = $this->admin_model->get_supplier();
                $data['asset_category'] = $this->admin_model->get_asset_category();
                $data['location'] = $this->admin_model->get_location();
                $data['room'] = $this->admin_model->get_room();
                $data['status'] = $this->admin_model->get_status();
                $this->load->view('frame/header_view');
                $this->load->view('frame/sidebar_nav_view');
                $this->load->view('asset/create_asset', $data);
        } 

        else

        {


        $name_array = array();
        $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
        foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
        for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) {
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];   
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/asset';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
            }
            $names= implode(',', $name_array);

            //Prepare array of user data
            $userData = array(
                    'name' => $this->input->post('asset_name'),
                    'item_description' => $this->input->post('asset_description'),
                    'brand' => $this->input->post('brand'),
                    'serial_number' => $this->input->post('asset_serial'),
                    'model' => $this->input->post('asset_model'),
                    'supplier' => $this->input->post('supplier'),
                    'category' => $this->input->post('asset_category'),
                    'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
                    'room' => $this->input->post('room'),
                    'date_pruchase' => $this->input->post('date_purchase'),
                    'purchase_price' => $this->input->post('purchase_price'),
                    'ip' => $this->input->post('ip'),
                    'mac' => $this->input->post('mac'),
                    'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
                    'files' => $names

                );

            //Pass user data to model
            $insertUserData = $this->admin_model->inset_asset($userData);

            //Storing insertion status message.
            if($insertUserData){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'User data have been added successfully.');
                print_r($userData);
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Some problems occured, please try again.');
            }
                redirect('admin/create_asset');
            }

        }

    }
```

Model

```
function inset_asset($data = array())
        {

            if(!array_key_exists("created",$data)){
                $data['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            }
            $insert = $this->db->insert('tbl_asset_register', $data);
            if($insert){
                return $this->db->insert_id();
            }else{
                return false;    
            }
        }
```

My table/asset view view.

```
function asset_list(){
            $data = array(
                'formTitle' => 'Open Calls',
                'title' => 'Open Calls',
                'asset' => $this->admin_model->get_asset_list(),
            );

            $this->load->view('frame/header_view');
            $this->load->view('frame/sidebar_nav_view');
            $this->load->view('asset/view_asset', $data);

        }

    function show_asset($id)
        {
            $data = array(

                'formTitle' => 'View Asset',
                'title' => 'Asset Management'
            );

                $data["data"] = $this->admin_model->get_assets('', '', $id);
                $this->load->view('frame/header_view');
                $this->load->view('frame/sidebar_nav_view');
                $this->load->view('asset/shows_asset', $data);        
        }
```

data table

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">      
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dtBasicExample">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Asset ID:</th>
                                <th>Name:</th>
                                <th>Location:</th>
                                <th>Room:</th>
                                <th>Serial No.:</th>
                                <th>View Images:</th>
                                <th><strong>Option</strong></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach($asset  as $row): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->location; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->room; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->serial_number; ?></td>
                                <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/show_asset/' . $row->id); ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">view</button></a></td>
                                <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/update_ob/' . $row->id); ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>



                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
```

view Page

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
                        <ul class="gallery">
                            <?php if(!empty($files)){ foreach($files as $file){ ?>
                            <li class="item">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/asset/'.$file['files']); ?>" >
                            </li>
                            <?php } }else{ ?>
                            <p>Image(s) not found.....</p>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

I am looking at two ways to go for the table view. One a button to click to view all images or one small image in the table.

In my view I want to view all the images at the bottom of my pages.